# Rewrite changing Url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'd like to use apaches mod_rewrite to rewrite my url's. Normally, that i could do that, but i think is a special case. The content on the page depends on the url parameters, but is also capable of altering those parameters, and thus gaining new content *without refreshing*. The same parameters would always give the same result, however.

My url currently looks like this:

```
http://example.com/#?div1=1&div2=5
```

I would like to be able to use a neat, clean url, like http://example.com/nameofarticle. Does using mod_rewrite prevent changing a parameter that is "hidden" beneath such a url? And if not, how can i use mod_rewrite in order to allow me to keep working like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) `%{QUERY_STRING}` before your RewriteRule. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} div1=(.*)&
```

Then you can access the bracketed values in the `RewriteRule` with `%1` ... Just as you'd use `$1` for bracketed values in the RewriteRule itself.

You may also want to be looking at the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) flag `[QSA]`. Quoting the `mod_rewrite` docs:

> - 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
>
> This flag forces the rewrite engine to
> append a query string part of the
> substitution string to the existing
> string, instead of replacing it. Use
> this when you want to add more data to
> the query string via a rewrite rule.

Comment: Could show provide an example of the combined use of both rules? I haven't used RewriteCond before. Thanks!

Comment: @Lg102 Yeah, can you show me the "path" you'd like to take to get from `http://example.com/#?div1=1&div2=5` to `http://example.com/nameofarticle`, then I can probably come up with something.